# Adding a if statement based on number of words in a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I managed to cobble together this statement based on lots of help and copying and pasting. It basically returns the first x number of words in a string and im using it as a helper in my app.

Could someone please help me understand how I would add a condition to say if the actual string is less than x words don't add the finishing bit (which is a ...). So in the equation below I' like the 'finish' section to only be added if they are more than the number of words passed into the equation.

```
 def first_x_words(str,n=20,finish='&hellip;')
    str.split(' ')[0,n].inject{|sum,word| sum + ' ' + word} + finish
 end
```

Actually - if I could  make it more complicated, is it possible, after I find a condition where there are less than x words, to check to see if the last 4 characters are `</p>` and if they are, remove them.

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'd probably want to use http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-truncate instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you're looking for:

```
def first_x_words(str, n = 20, finish = '&hellip;')
  # By default, Ruby will split on whitespace, so no
  # argument needs to be passed.
  words = str.split

  # Rebuild 'n' words into a new string.
  truncated = words[0..n-1].inject do |sum, word|
    sum << ' ' << word
  end

  # Either append a finishing string or remove any
  # trailing '</p>' tag.
  if words.length > n
    truncated << finish
  else
    truncated.chomp!("</p>")
  end

  # Return the completed string.
  truncated
end
```

Comment: Changed the bottom a little to account for the </p> check:

Comment: if words.length > n
        truncated << finish
      else
        if str.slice(str.length - 4, str.length) == "</p>" then
        truncated = str.slice(0,str.length - 4)
        else
        truncted = str
        end
      end

Comment: @Adam: Thanks for the update. I've added a similar implementation (using `chomp` because it's fail-safe) to the code along with some code comments for future Ruby newcomers. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It's messy but if you really want to do it

```
def first_x_words(str,n=20,finish='&hellip;')
  # make finish blank if the text is short enough
  finish = '' if str.split(' ').count < n
  str.split(' ')[0,n].inject{|sum,word| sum + ' ' + word} + finish
  # remove trailing </p> if any
  str.chomp('</p>')
end
```

I added one line of code before and after your original code so you can hopefully understand it better.